# How can I nest InnerBlocks inside InnerBlocks (custom plugins)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am building a custom Wordpress site with a bunch of new plugins. I have a couple of plugins that use `InnerBlocks`, which work fine. However, for some of these plugins I would like to add `InnerBlocks` inside the child plugin. When I am in editing mode, I can render the `InnerBlocks`, but when saving and reloading, the data of the `InnerBlocks` disappear. I have tried to read through the `core/columns` and `core/column` code, but it's built significantly different than my code and therefore difficult to understand. But, since colums and column can be nested, I should be able to do the same.

These are my files:

```
// gallery/edit.js
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { useSelect } from "@wordpress/data";
import { useEffect } from "@wordpress/element";
import { InnerBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

const Edit = (props) => {
    const { setAttributes, clientId } = props;

    const { innerBlockCount } = useSelect((select) => ({
        innerBlockCount: select("core/block-editor").getBlockCount(clientId),
    }));
    useEffect(() => {
        setAttributes({ innerBlockCount });
    }, [innerBlockCount]);

    const ALLOWED_BLOCKS = ["dyrlaegetorvet/gallery-image"];

    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <section class="p-0">
                <div class="flex-editor__gallery">
                    <InnerBlocks
                        orientation="horizontal"
                        allowedBlocks={ALLOWED_BLOCKS}
                    />
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Edit;
```

```
// gallery-image/edit.js
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import {
  useBlockProps,
  InnerBlocks,
} from "@wordpress/block-editor";

const Edit = (props) => {
  const blockProps = useBlockProps();

  return (
    <div {...blockProps}>
      <div class="p-4">
        <div class="tpl-image aspect-w-3 aspect-h-4">
          <InnerBlocks
            placeholder="Insert an image"
            allowedBlocks={["core/image"]}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Edit;
```

Comment: Are you able to share your save.js? The innerBlocks need to be implemented in save() as well as edit.

Comment: OMG @S. Walsh! This is such a silly oversight. Actually, none of my child plugins have a save() function as I am outputting all content through PHP. However, in order to save InnerBlock content I have to add the save() function again. I tried it and it works like a charm (and exactly what I expected). Thanks for the tip.